# Angular tests: ngOnInit method which depends on the template and document object

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I developed an application with Angular (2+) and now I'm testing every single application `.ts` file to get a good percentage of code coverage.
I have a problem. I'm testing a component that in the `ngOnInit` life cycle method uses the `document` object to refer to some elements of the HTML template. This is a code sample:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   element;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.element = document.getElementById('myElementId');
      this.element.className = 'blur'
   }

}
```

where `myElementId` is a `<div>` element of my template.
As for the test, here's part of the code:

```
describe('MyComponent  Tests', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let component: MyComponent;
  let rootElement: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [MyComponentModule,  RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })    
  });
});
    
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IndexPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    rootElement = fixture.debugElement;
  });

  it("Should created", fakeAsync(() => {

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

  }));

});
```

When I start the test it gives me a FAILED result with this error: **Cannot set property 'className' of null**.  Basically the line `fixture.detectChanges()` activates the `ngOnInit()` method of my component, but it is as if the component instance on the test file **is not linked with the HTML template!**.
For this reason the line `this.element.className = 'blur'`, fundamental for the functioning of the component, is evaluated as if it were a null pointer.
How can I solve this problem and test the component well?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by angular, try not to change the DOM in the code.

Instead, your template should be like:

```
<myElementId [class]="ElementIdClass" / >
```

And in your `ngOnInit`, something like:

```
ElementIdClass = "blur"
```

Then it will be easier to test the .ts